# Retrieve a record base on last Auto Increment primary key and view in input field

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, last-insert-id

I want to retrieve a record from a table in database base on last primary key insert(the ID), this how my program looks like, but when i run it'll return to blank page. Is the query wrong??

```
<div style="background:steelblue;">
    <form action=saveRecord.jsp> <<----will save the record to other table
        <%
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection conn =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dssps", "root", "admin");
        String query = "select Did,ShipName,Origin,Port1 from decsfinal where   Did=LAST_INSERT_ID()";
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        if(rs.next()){
        %>

        <label>ID</label>
        <input  name="Did" value="<%=rs.getInt("Did")%>">
        </br>

        <label>Ship Name</label>
        <input  name="ShipName" value="<%=rs.getString("ShipName")%>">
        </br>

        <label>Origin Port</label>
        <input  name="Origin" value="<%=rs.getString("Origin")%>">
        </br>

        <label>Destination Port</label>
        <input  name="Port1" value="<%=rs.getString("Port1")%>">
        </br>

        // here the submit button and close database
```

Answer (score -1):

last_insert_id() method is retrieving last_id+1 means if you have last id as 9 it is retrieving 10 and comparing it in the where clause, hence there is no id which is equal to 10 your query is retrieving null, try this query(it worked for me).

`select Did,ShipName,Origin,Port1 from decsfinal where Did =  Last_insert_id()-1;`

OR
if your primary key(Did) is set to auto increment you can use this query to get result you want

`select max(Did) , ShipName ,Origin,Port1 from decsfinal;`